# Does easy thumbnails for django work for apache server?

Tags: html, django, apache

I have a page, which is served by apache. When I upload images by the django's server (on localhost:8000) page, it does show me the uploaded image properly. However when I upload images by the apache server (on localhost) page, it does not show the uploaded image. Only when I reload the page on the django's inbuilt server (localhost:8000) i can see it on both the page served by the apache and django's server.

This was the index.html:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load thumbnail %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>leo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">
    </head>
....
....
```

And here's the other part of it for image:

```
                        {% for Status in status %}
                            <p class="user">{{ Status.creator.get_full_name }}</p>
                            {% if Status.image %}
                                <div class="image_image">
                                    <center>
                                    <img src="{{Status.image |thumbnail_url:'status'}}"/>
                                    </center>
                                </div>
                                <p class="status_image">{{Status}}</p>
                                <span class="clear"></span>
                                <hr>
                            {% else %}
                                <p class="status_status">{{Status}}</p>
                                <span class="clear_right"></span>
                                <hr>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
```

After I removed the EASY THUMBNAILS tag from the html file and made these changes on the html file, I was ok.

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
....
....
```

And this:

```
                            <div class="image_image">
                                <center>
                                <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{Status.image}}" width=300px />
                                </center>
                            </div>
```

Why is apache behaving so? And also in the uploaded directory it was creating an extra image for the same image. I guess this is because easy thumbnails creates a new thumbnail for the image. Am I wrong somewhere? Is it the problem of easy_thumbnails tag??? If it is. How do I make it work. Or else how can I a achieve thumbnails of the images like easy thumbnails? Please guide me. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe apache doesn't have write permission on the images / uploads folder?

Comment: @YuriPrezument That's what I think... Can I grant permission for that?

Comment: If you're on linux/mac - make sure that the folder is writeable by apache. E.g. set the group to `www-data` or `apache` (depends on the OS), and do `chmod -R g+w [MEDIA_FOLDER]` to make the folder writeable by the group apache is running under.

Comment: @YuriPrezument Oh.. M on windows! Know anything about that?

Comment: No idea how it works on windows... you can try checking the apache error logs

Comment: Forgot about this one... you should set `THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True` in the settings.
It makes easy-thumbnails show throw errors when failing to make a thumbnail instead of failing silently.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I will try this and inform you!